# Operator in a generic Hilbert space $H$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

In an Hibert space $H$ with orthonormal basis $\{e_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$, let $T_n$ be the operator defined by the action
$$
T_nx=(x, e_{n+1})e_n.
$$
Compute its norm, eigenvalues and eigenvectors e show that for any $x\in H$, the sequence $\left\{\sum_{n=-N}^NT_nx\right\}_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges.

**My attempt.** No problem about computing the norm, eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I find out that the norm is $1$. Now, to show that the sequence converges, I notice that
$$
\sum_{n=-N}^N(x, e_{n+1})e_n=\sum_{n=-N}^Nx_{n+1}\leq M.
$$
How can I conclude that the sequence converges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y_N:=\sum_{n=-N}^NT_nx$. Then for each $M\geqslant N$, 
$$y_M-y_N=\sum_{n=N+1}^M\left(x, e_{n+1}\right)e_n+\sum_{n=-M}^{-N-1}\left(x, e_{n+1}\right)e_n$$
and using orthogonality of  the family $\{e_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$, we derive that 
$$
\left\lVert y_M-y_N\right\rVert^2=\sum_{n=N+1}^M\left(x, e_{n+1}\right)^2+\sum_{n=-M}^{-N-1}\left(x, e_{n+1}\right)^2.
$$
To conclude, it suffice to show that the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \left(x, e_{n+1}\right)^2$ converges, which is usually done by using orthogonal projection on the vector space generated by $\{e_k\}_{k=-j}^j$.